# Azure B2C user has no access permissions to change password of unsigned user via Graph API

Tags: c#, azure, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

I create graph api:

```
IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
                .Create(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAdB2C").GetValue<string>("ApplicationId"))
                .WithTenantId(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAdB2C").GetValue<string>("TenantId"))
                .WithClientSecret(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAdB2C").GetValue<string>("ClientSecret"))
                .Build();
            ClientCredentialProvider authProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(confidentialClientApplication);
            GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);
            _graphClient = graphClient;
```

and try to call update user password:

```
User user = new User()
            {
                PasswordProfile = new PasswordProfile
                {
                    Password = "123456aaA@",
                    ForceChangePasswordNextSignIn = false,
                    ForceChangePasswordNextSignInWithMfa = false
                },
            };
            await _graphClient.Users[entity.Id.ToString()].Request().UpdateAsync(user);
```

but when executed, it gives an error that we have not enough permissions:

```
Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=Code: Authorization_RequestDenied
Message: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.
Inner error:
    AdditionalData:
    date: 2021-06-25T12:18:57
    request-id: 424cffe2-8775-440c-ad0d-c894194cd9c7
    client-request-id: 424cffe2-8775-440c-ad0d-c894194cd9c7
ClientRequestId: 424cffe2-8775-440c-ad0d-c894194cd9c7
```

[Permissions in Azure for Graph:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjuFz.png)

What permission i need to add ?

Answer (score 0):

When updating the `passwordProfile` property, the following permission is required: `Directory.AccessAsUser.All`

(From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

Comment: In AD B2C we haven't permisson Directory.AccessAsUser.All